# Can I post form asynchronously to secure (https) url?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a form on html page and some javascript code that posts it using AJAX via jQuery. When I run function that performs POST operation it doesn't appear to take any effect, but synchronous POST does work (I test it via submit button). Can problem be related to the fact that action url of the form looks like https://****************** ?

Comment: Could you pass the code asynchronous call?

Comment: function SubmitForm() {
            var frm = $("#form2");
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function(results) {
                    // do stuff
                    alert(results);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    // handle the error
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can POST asynchronously to HTTPS with XHR.**

However, cross-site posting is generally disallowed and something as silly as a bad/unknown certificate may throw the process off. On the other hand, it could just be a blatant bug in the code. Follow with standard debugging procedures using a tool that can monitor XHR requests, such as Firebug and pay attention ("use") the XHR error handling mechanisms.

[Same Origin Policy, Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

[HTTP Access Control, Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: What I do is exactly cross-site posting. I test it on my local host and post it to the remote server.

Comment: Cross-site posting (in this context) is trying to send an XHR request to another *domain* (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control). The URI is compared and, generally, if it does not match the attempt is denied; allegedly for security concerns. This behavior can be changed in some browsers, such as in IE. Also, some newer initiatives (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Cross_Site_XMLHttpRequest) are [re]-allowing cross-site (cross-domain) access.